# Confusion regarding the correct modal to be used in the sentence

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

There was a question asked in my board exam. I want to know the most appropriate option.
Question: Select the correct option to fill in the blank for the given sentence:
.......you help me cross the road, young man?
(a) Will
(b) May
(c) Shall
(d) Might

Comment: Will is correct.

Comment: *Might* can be used to make a request or suggestion, although [this page](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/might-and-may-modals) says it's very formal. *Will* is less formal. But I'm not totally sure which they are wanting - it's a question of etiquette or manners.